# Two line label text in D3 circle packing

Tags: javascript, d3.js, circle-pack

I've searched the current topics in this site, but no solution solved my problem.

How can I show text in two line for long length texts in D3 circle packing. I'm using following code to show labels on circles:

```
const label = svg.append("g")
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .attr("pointer-events", "none")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")    
      .selectAll("text")
      .data(root.descendants())
      .join("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", d => d.parent === root ? 1 : 0)
      .style("text-shadow", "0px 0px 11px #FFF")
      .style("display", d => d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none")
      .attr("dy", "0.3em")
      .text(d => d.data.name);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG does not have a built in wrap text option to automatically split lines for long texts. There is a wrap function described here https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321 by Mike Bostock which splits the text into appropriate lines when you provide the `text` and the `width` attributes.

```
function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

You can invoke it by calling it on the selection using `selectAll(".textclass").call(wrap,textwidth)` where `textclass` is the class of the text you want to wrap and `textwidth` is the width of the text allowed.